# Central Limit Theorem to determine approximate probability

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

Ten numbers are rounded to the nearest integer and then summed.I want to determine the approximate probability that the sum of the unrounded numbers equals the rounded sum of the original numbers.

To solve this question, I have firstly assumed that the fractional part of each number is uniformly distributed.Then i started by applying the central limit theorem but couldn't proceed further.

Can someone give me hint on how to proceed further.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question as asked is $0$ since the distribution of the sum of the unrounded numbers is continuous and the probability that a variable with a continuous distribution equals an integer is $0$. I have therefore answered the question as I thought it might be intended: Find the probability that the rounded sum of the variables is equal to the sum of the rounded variables.

**Computing the Probability**

Let the probability density $f(x)=\left[|x|\le\frac12\right]$, where $[\dots]$ are [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). The variance of the distribution with the density $f$ is $\frac1{12}$. The probability that the rounded sum of the variables is equal to the sum of the rounded variables is the same as the probability that the sum of the rounding errors is between $-\frac12$ and $\frac12$. That is,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\overbrace{f\ast f\ast\cdots\ast f}^{10\ f\text{s}}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac{381773117}{928972800}\\
&\doteq0.41096
\end{align}
$$

---

**Approximation Using the Central Limit Theorem**

The variance of $\overbrace{f\ast f\ast\cdots\ast f}^{10\ f\text{s}}$ is $10\cdot\frac1{12}=\frac56$. Thus, $\frac12$ is $\sqrt{\frac3{10}}$ standard deviations. Therefore, the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) says the probability that the rounded sum of the variables is equal to the sum of the rounded variables is approximately
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\sqrt{\frac3{10}}}^{\sqrt{\frac3{10}}}e^{-t^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}t\doteq0.41612}
$$

---

**Evaluation Using the Fourier Transform**

The Fourier Transform of $f$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(\xi)
&=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{\sin(\pi\xi)}{\pi\xi}
\end{align}
$$
Since the Fourier Transform of a convolution is the product of the Fourier Transforms, and vice-versa, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\overbrace{f\ast f\ast\cdots\ast f}^{n\ f\text{s}}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\overbrace{f\ast f\ast\cdots\ast f}^{n\ f\text{s}}(x)\,f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{f}(\xi)^n\hat{f}(-\xi)\,\mathrm{d}\xi\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac{\sin(\pi\xi)}{\pi\xi}\right)^{n+1}\mathrm{d}\xi
\end{align}
$$
which, using contour integration, evaluates to
$$
\frac1{2^nn!}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n+1}{k}(n-2k+1)^n
$$
Setting $n=10$ yields $\frac{381773117}{928972800}$, as above.

Comment: For $n$ numbers, the probability is asymptotic to $\sqrt{\frac6{n\pi}}$. For $n=10$, this gives $0.43702$, but the approximation gets better as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Will u explain me how that integral of exponential part come? We had not studied that part.We just learned Statement of Central Limit theorem.

Comment: @BhushanJamsandekar: The version of the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) that I am using says that the "sum of many independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables...will tend to be distributed according to...the normal distribution." The mean and variance of the approximating normal distribution will be the sum of the means and variances of the random variables. In this case we have $10$ random variables, each with mean $0$ and variance $\frac1{12}$. Thus, the normal distribution should have mean $0$ and variance $\frac{10}{12}$.

Comment: This means that the approximating normal distribution has a standard deviation of $\sqrt{\frac56}$, so $\frac12$ is $\sqrt{\frac3{10}}$ standard deviations above the mean and $-\frac12$ is $\sqrt{\frac3{10}}$ standard deviations below the mean. The integral computes the probability of a normal random variable being in that range. As shown, the probability from the approximating normal distribution is close to the actual probability.

Comment: But we are supposed to find the approximate probability that the rounded sum of the original numbers equals the sum of the unrounded numbers.But you have shown that the rounded sum of original numbers equals the sum of rounded numbers.How can we prove that?

Comment: @BhushanJamsandekar: I have added a preamble explaining why the answer to the question as asked is $0$ and why I answered what I did.